# pointer to an object has no any value (or do not get a value)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

i have a problem with output of 2 classes like below:

foo.h

```
public:
    Foo(){} ;
    Foo(string);
    Foo(const Foo&);
    string getFooName() const;
    ~Foo();
private:
    string foo;
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(string n):foo(n){
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo &f):foo(f.foo){
}

string Foo::getFooName() const{
    return foo;
}

Foo::~Foo(){
}
```

and class Bar:

Bar.h

```
public:
    Bar();
    Bar(string, Foo&);
    Bar(const Bar&);
    Foo& getFoo() const;
    ~Bar();
private:
    string bar;
    Foo* foo;
};
```

Bar.cpp

```
Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo()){
}

Bar::Bar(const Bar &b):bar(b.bar), foo(new Foo(*b.foo)){
}

Foo &Bar::getFoo() const{
 return *foo;
}

Bar::~Bar()
{
delete foo;
}
```

and in main fuction, when i use this `cout<<"Test:"<<b->getFoo().getFooName();` it only gets me in output only `Test:` instead of `Test:TestFoo`.

what is wrong in my code? (gcc5.4.0,cmake 3.5.1)
tnx

and main.cpp

```
Foo* f;
Bar* b;
f=new Foo("TestFoo");
b=new Bar("TestBar",*f);  
cout<<"Test:"<<b->getFoo().getFooName(); // this line
```

Comment: `Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo()){` Your constructor `foo` argument is ignored and new empty `Foo` instance is always created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo()){}
```

Parameter `f` is unused. You need pass it to the `Foo` constructor.

```
Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo(f)){}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
b = new Bar("TestBar", *f);
```

the following constructor is called:

```
Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo())
```

As you can see, the second parameter is not used to initialize the foo member, but a new one created instead. Its not the same object which you initialized with the "TestFoo"!

So when you print, "TestFoo" is not returned at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in `Bar.cpp`:

The first constructor for `Bar` is

```
Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo()){
}
```

This tells the compiler to create a pointer to a new `Foo` object to store in the `Bar` object. However, new `Foo` object has nothing to do with the `Foo` object passed as input to the constructor.  The constructor needs to use the `Foo` object passed as an input so that the new `Foo` object has the same value in the member variable `foo`:

```
Bar::Bar(string b, Foo &f):bar(b), foo(new Foo(f.foo)){
}
```

Then, the constructor call

```
b=new Bar("TestBar",*f);
```

in `main.cpp` will actually assign the member variable `foo` a value of "TestFoo" (whereas before it was not initializing the variable).

As a result, `b->getFoo().getFooName()` should return "TestFoo" as desired.